# Calculating the sample size

Tags: calculus, probability, random-variables, confidence-interval

I have :

$$2z \frac{\sqrt{pq/n + z^2/4n^2}}{1+z^2/n} = w$$

and I want to demonstrate that
  $$n = \frac{2x^2pq - z^2w^2 ~\pm~ \sqrt{4z^4pq(pq - w^2) + w^2z^4}}{w^2}.$$

Can someone give me a detailed solution?

I tried to solve it and at the end I got 
$$
\frac{pq}{n} + \frac{z^2(1-w^2)}{4n^2} = \frac{w^2}{4z^2} + \frac{w^2}{2},
$$ 
but I am not sure if this is correct and I am even lost to find the exact solution for $n$.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: You might want to give the problem this is for.  The clue that this is about confidence intervals and random variables (and sample size) isn't enough context.

Comment: But in fact it is just how to solve this quadratic function. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply your last equation by $4n^2$ you get a degree 2 polynomial equation. 
$$
ax^2+bx+c=0.
$$
The generic solution 
$$
n={-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\over 2a}
$$
looks a lot like what you are looking for...